# Install vegan package for R via terminal command

Tags: command-line, package-management, r

Hi I want to install the vegan package for R via terminal command - so far I have this:

This downloads the zipped file required (*this part works*)

```
wget -O ~/file/downloads/vegan_2.3-5.tar.gz "http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/vegan_2.3-5.tar.gz"
```

I want this to then install that package so i can run it in R (*this part doesn't work* error message: syntax error near unexpected token `('
)

```
install.packages(~/file/downloads/vegan_2.3-5.tar.gz, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"this part doesn't work"*? it doesn't give us much to go on

Comment: Use this terminal command to install the downloaded package `R CMD INSTALL vegan_2.3-5.tar.gz`

Comment: still get error with this but now it says: * installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
ERROR: dependency ‘permute’ is not available for package ‘vegan’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/vegan’

Comment: Is there a reason you can't install vegan the standard way from within R? install.packages("vegan") should automatically pull on any dependencies.

Comment: i prefer to do things via the command line rather than within R, makes things easier for larger script writing and install packages etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've got the answer, thanks rcs for the install method. Basically `vegan` requires previous installation of `permute`. So these commands do the trick:

```
wget -O ~/downloads/permute_0.8-3.tar.gz "http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/permute_0.8-3.tar.gz"
wget -O ~/downloads/vegan_2.3-5.tar.gz "http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/vegan_2.3-5.tar.gz"
sudo R CMD INSTALL ~/downloads/permute_0.8-3.tar.gz
sudo R CMD INSTALL ~/downloads/vegan_2.3-5.tar.gz
```